# How to write order by in findByPk in yii

Tags: php, yii

I wrote like this, but its not working,

```
$project_name = ProjectsMaster::model()->findByPk($projectcode,array('order'=>'project'));
```

Comment: i think if you are using findByPk then you will get only 1 row so why you want to use ORDER BY

Comment: @Dinesh Bhojvani- you are right buddy.

Comment: find by PK will return one record, why do you wanna use ORDER BY?

Answer (score 0):

you no need to write `ORDER BY` becasue you are using `findByPk` which returns only single row. so no need to used `ORDER BY` just try like below code.

```
$project_name = ProjectsMaster::model()->findByPk($projectcode);
```